# web2py controller returns value to <div id

Tags: jquery, web2py

I've read and read and read and I don't understand why this isn't clicking for me.

In my web2py controller my index() method returns a value:

```
return dict(cli="steve")
```

In the code of the view I have a div

```
{{=cli}}
```

What is rendered in the page is

> **cli**: steve
>
> steve

Where I'm trying to get is for the view's html to have a div I define which should be as simple as:

```
<div id='cli'>{{=cli}}</div>
```

but what is with & how do I prevent the additional

> **cli**: steve

that is being rendered?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to show the code of the view.

Comment: May be you forgot to remove this line `{{=BEAUTIFY(response._vars)}}` from your view.

Comment: @Anthony all 300 lines of html?

Comment: I'm considering this line which is the index view built by web2py `{{if 'message' in globals():}} <h2>{{=message}}</h2>`  ... How do I tell my controller to insert 'cli' in globals()?

Comment: @user2367083, maybe not 300 lines of html, but something more than zero.

Comment: When the controller returns a dictionary, its keys are added as variables in the global environment of the subsequently executed view. So, in this case, "cli" will already be in `globals()` within the view environment.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what I changed but this morning it is working.

-- from the return of the controller ---

```
return dict(cli="steve")
```

-- from the html of the view

```
<div id="cli">{{=cli}}</div>
```

I played with the html by reorganizing about three dozen things.
I can't get it back to how it behaved last night.
With that I can only assume something I changed on the controller fixed this issue. But I can't imagine what that was.

The code you see in the original question an in this posted answer is unchanged.

Maybe I was fighting a browser cache fluke? (Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87)
Thanks anyway.

Comment: I agree with the comment above -- you probably had something like `{{=BEAUTIFY(response._vars)}}` in the view (that line is in the "index.html" view included with the scaffolding app and will be executed unless your controller dictionary has a "message" or "content" key).

Comment: Actually my =BEAUTIFY() is in a comment block in the html.  But I will play with that specifically and see what I can make happen.  Last night when I was playing with the code inside the comment block it didn't seen to be doing anything.  But at that time I didn't understand why it wasn't